# Error with ampersand in XML in Zoho API

Tags: xml, zoho

I'm using the Zoho API to insert leads into the CRM.

Everything is working fine except when one of the fields contains an ampersand, in which case the response from Zoho is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords">
  <error>
    <code>4835</code>
    <message>Unable to parse XML data</message>
  </error>
</response>
```

I've tried the following payloads without any success:

**1/**

```
<Leads>
    <row no="1">
        <FL val="Lead Owner">me@example.com</FL>
        <FL val="Company">Marks & Spencer</FL>
    </row>
</Leads>
```

**2/**

```
<Leads>
    <row no="1">
        <FL val="Lead Owner">me@example.com</FL>
        <FL val="Company">Marks &amp; Spencer</FL>
    </row>
</Leads>
```

**3/**

```
<Leads>
    <row no="1">
        <FL val="Lead Owner">me@example.com</FL>
        <FL val="Company">Marks &#038; Spencer</FL>
    </row>
</Leads>
```

**4/**

```
<Leads>
    <row no="1">
        <FL val="Lead Owner">me@example.com</FL>
        <FL val="Company"><![CDATA[Marks &amp; Spencer]]></FL>
    </row>
</Leads>
```

I've even tested by replacing the ampersand by `%26` as advised on this [Zoho forum thread](https://forums.zoho.com/topic/api-throws-error-when-passing-ampersand-and-via-xml) but with no luck.

What is the correct format to encode ampersands for Zoho queries?

Comment: A bit absurd though, but can you please try &amp;amp; ? There may be a double rendering issue.

Comment: Thanks @AndrásHummer ! I've finally found a solution to this problem (see below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found a solution: strings containing a special characters must be contained in `CDATA` sections **AND** those special characters need to be [percent encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).

So for the example above, this gives:

```
<Leads>
    <row no="1">
        <FL val="Lead Owner">me@example.com</FL>
        <FL val="Company"><![CDATA[Marks %26 Spencer]]></FL>
    </row>
</Leads>
```

Note that the value `Marks%20%26%20Spencer` is also OK for the API.

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to mark it as solution as well!

Comment: This doesn't work any more or at least not consistently. I have tested with data with 4 ampersand and the rest of the message is cut off from 2nd CDATA.